# If p and $8p^2+1$ are prime numbers then $p=3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove the statement above.

Any hints?

Comment: Consider divisibility by $3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact you want to prove in previous post: if $3\nmid n$ then $3\mid n^2-1$.

If $p\ne 3$ then $3\mid p^2-1$ so $$3\mid 9p^2-(p^2-1)= 8p^2+1$$ so $8p^2+1=3$ which is impossible. So $p=3$.

Comment: (+1) Cute… and fast!